# Redraw NSView with subviews programmatically

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nsview

I have an **NSTableView** that I want to have a nice looking view over when it's empty. It looks like this:

[image]

I have added the TableView inside a custom view (*_superViewPackages*) with the same size, and then added this code to the **numberOfRowsInTableView** function to show/hide the overlay:

```
if ( count == 0 && [[[_superViewPackages subviews] firstObject] isNotEqualTo:_viewOverlayPackages] ) {
        [_superViewPackages addSubview:_viewOverlayPackages positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
        [_viewOverlayPackages setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        NSArray *constraintsArray;
        constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-1-[_viewOverlayPackages]-1-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_viewOverlayPackages)];
        [_superViewPackages addConstraints:constraintsArray];
        constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-1-[_viewOverlayPackages]-1-|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_viewOverlayPackages)];
        [_superViewPackages addConstraints:constraintsArray];
    } else if ( count > 0 && [[_superViewPackages subviews] containsObject:_viewOverlayPackages] ) {
        [_viewOverlayPackages removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

This works, but when I remove the last item in the tableView, it won't update until I either click on another tab and back again, or on another application and back again and the application redraws everything.

I have tried a number of combinations of **setNeedsDisplay**, **setNeedsLayout** and **setNeedsUpdateConstraints** on multiple different views but none have worked. I have also moved the updating to its own method and is invoking it with **performSelectorOnMainThread** to get around any threading problem.

I'm fairly new to Objective-C, so this might be obvious to someone with more experience, but after reading and testing I still can't find what really needs to be called to update.

Right now I have included this code after adding the last constraint:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateView:) withObject:_viewOverlayPackages waitUntilDone:NO];
```

In the **withObject** arg I have tried adding all views I can think of but none have worked.

```
- (void)updateView:(NSView *)view {
    NSLog(@"updateView %@", view);
    [view setNeedsUpdateConstraints:YES];
    [view updateConstraintsForSubtreeIfNeeded];
    [view setNeedsLayout:YES];
    [view layoutSubtreeIfNeeded];
    [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [view display];
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding screenshots for clarification.

When the table view contains items, it looks like this:

[image]

But, when I remove the last item, and the TableView becomes empty, I want it to look like the screenshot at the top of the post. Instead, it looks like this until I click on another tab and back, or on another application and back etc. Then it updates correctly.

[image]

So as i can tell, the view gets added correctly, and I have checked that, It's just that the application doesn't redraw correctly until do something that makes it redraw everything (is my guess).

Comment: R U want to reload your view with new values,right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, added more screenshots to make it more clear what I want.

Comment: can you try when you want to reload view than first remove it from super view and than readded it with new data?

Comment: How about showing/hiding the views? Don't remove them. Also don't do this in your datasource methods. A better place is where the data changes, instead of when the tableview ask for it.

Comment: Thank you Willeke, that was pretty obvious, and to be honest I didn't know I could set a view as hidden, and I was probably too focused on the way I implemented it as it *almost* worked. I add the view in initialization and just set it as hidden when i insert items into the table view (moved that from the datasource methods as well). So that was a much better approach than what I had done. Thank you so much!